# Change the catcode and then define a (Unicode) character

Tags: xetex, luatex, catcodes

The motivation is that I sometimes have, e.g.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\catcode`¯=\active
\def¯#1#2{\overline{#1#2}}
$¯ab+¯bc=¯ac$
```

in my code.
I thought it would be nice if there is a macro, say `\activatedefine`,
such that

```
\activatedefine¯#1#2{\overline{#1#2}}
```

does the job that `\catcode` and `\def` do.

I understand that it is not correct to write

```
\def\activatedefine#1{
    \catcode`#1=active
    \def#1
}
```

because the catcode of the `#1` in the third line is not changed.
But then I hear that `\futurelet` can duplicate tokens.
So I came up with

```
\def\activatedefine{
    \futurelet\thechar\nowwecanplaywiththechar
}
\def\nowwecanplaywiththechar{
    \expandafter\catcode\expandafter`\thechar=13
    \def
}
```

This is still not quite right because `\thechar` does not expand to `¯`.
So I try to fix it

```
\def\activatedefine{
    \futurelet\thechar\nowwecanplaywiththechar
}
\def\gobbletwo#1 #2 {}
\def\nowwecanplaywiththechar{
    \edef\activatethechar{
        \noexpand\catcode`\expandafter\gobbletwo\meaning\thechar=\active
    }
    %\message{^^J^^J \string\activatethechar is \meaning\activatethechar}
    \activatethechar
    %\message{^^J The catcode becomes \the\catcode`¯^^J^^J}
    \def
}
\activatedefine¯#1#2{\overline{#1#2}}
```

This macro does change the catcode of `¯` to `13`.
But TeX complains `Missing control sequence inserted`.

What is going wrong with my code?

## Edit

Almost forgot MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\activatedefine{\futurelet\thechar\nowwecanplaywiththechar}
%\def\nowwecanplaywiththechar{
%   \expandafter\catcode\expandafter`\thechar=13
%   \def
%}

\def\gobbletwo#1 #2 {}
\def\nowwecanplaywiththechar{%
    \edef\activatethechar{%
        \noexpand\catcode`\expandafter\gobbletwo\meaning\thechar=\active
    }
    \message{^^J^^J \string\activatethechar is \meaning\activatethechar}
    \activatethechar
    \message{^^J The catcode becomes \the\catcode`¯^^J^^J}
    \def¯
}
\activatedefine¯#1#2{\overline{#1#2}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: using `\futurelet` will freeze the catcode of the next token (the one to which the macro is let). This may or not be relevant to your problems (I admit not having read in detail).

Comment: It's not a good idea to make the back quote active.

Comment: also what do you mean by Uniocde here? if you are using pdftex you can only define single byte tokens this way not arbitrary unicode characters.

Comment: @jfbu That `\futurelet` will freeze the catcode is unexpected (by me). That answers why TeX complains.

Comment: @egreg I did not want to make back quote active. If my code did that it is unintended. I (only) want to make non-ASCII characters active.

Comment: oh I see in the comment in your mwe you are using xetex, you should probably tag the question xetex if you want xetex answers (the situation for pdftex is rather different)  actually your simplest solution is to use @egreg's newunicodechar package

Comment: ah you are using xetex!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I fix the tag.

Comment: @jfbu Sorry... I fix the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\activatedefine#1{\begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
                      \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}}%

\activatedefine¯#1#2{\overline{#1#2}}

\begin{document}

$¯ab+¯bc=¯ac$
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\activatedefine#1{\begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
                      \lowercase{\endgroup\catcode`#1\active\def~}}%

\activatedefine|#1#2{\overline{#1#2}}

\begin{document}
$|ab+|bc=|ac$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I did not pay much attention to the actual macro, which is in math mode so math active would be possibly better.

Besides I don't want to have to handle UTF-8, so I used `|` rather for the example.

---

AH! but OP is using XeTeX. So we can do this

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\activatedefine#1{\begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
                      \lowercase{\endgroup\catcode`#1\active\def~}}%

\activatedefine¯#1#2{\overline{#1#2}}

\begin{document}
\the\catcode`¯ % ONLY XETEX, NOT PDFTEX!

$¯ab+¯bc=¯ac$
\end{document}
% Local variables:
% TeX-engine: xetex
% End:
```

[image]

Problem with pdflatex is that `¯` is multibyte, and the erased code at top of my answer was redefinig the first byte, breaking LaTeX UTF-8.

Comment: Yes sorry  don't take any notice of me

Comment: @jfbu Your trick works in XeLaTeX. Are you suggesting that `\lowercase` will reevaluate the catcode of `¯`?

Comment: The tilde is active. The `\lowercase` modifies the character code, but keeps the category code. So it creates an active token, which we can define. Then we must not forget to actually make this character associated to active category code.

Comment: @jfbu Where can I find the exact behavior of `\lowercase`, including what you just said? Why on earth can `\lowercase` contains assignments... This blows my mind.

Comment: TeX by Topic `3.6.4 Creative use of \uppercase and \lowercase`. A bit terse... but search this site for `egreg+lowercase` for many many examples. See also a bit earlier in TeX by Topic `3.6.2 Uppercase and lowercase commands`.

Comment: *the erased code at top of my answer was redefinig the first byte,*: I forgot to add *when used with pdflatex*. That's the point, with `xelatex`, the Unicode character `¯` is handled as one entity, with `pdflatex` and document in utf-8 inputenc (now tacit with recent LaTeX), it is two TeX tokens, the first one being active but shared with many other such characters. So there was no proble with erased code (except the missing activation of character), but its application to `¯` was working by accident with `pdflatex` and would have broken other things. With `xelatex`, no issue.

Comment: What does `\the\catcode` do? I use XeTeX and I would like to know.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use `\newunicodechar`; it just defines parameterless macros, but we can exploit the fact TeX is a macro expansion language to begin with.

Note that these examples can be used with *all* TeX engines (except Knuth TeX).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{‾}{\overline}

\newcommand{\twooverline}[2]{\overline{#1#2}}
\newunicodechar{﹌}{\twooverline}

\begin{document}

$‾a$ $﹌ab$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\makeatletter
\newunicodechar{‾}{\symbol@overline}
\def\symbol@overline#1‾{\overline{#1}} % must go second

\begin{document}

$‾abc‾$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see what you mean. I prefer @jfbu's answer because I prefer a local trick. I prefer local trick because I want `\def•{circle(.2)}` in some TikZ picture but `\def•{\bullet}` outside the picture.

Comment: @Symbol1 Using the same symbol or macro for two different meanings is not what I'd recommend.

Comment: @Symbol1 Anyway, you can do `\newunicodechar{•}{\bullet}` in the preamble and `\def•{circle(.2)}` in the TikZ picture, if you so like (only XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX).

Comment: Yes, I know it is not a good practice. I usually include [tag:unicode-math] so for this very particular case `•` is already the bullet symbol (of catcode 12). And my strategy here is to [re]define `•` in TikZ as local as possible.

Comment: I want to say that I do have very good reason to use unicode in TikZ. For instance https://gist.github.com/Symbol1/597b2433dc402b5711af37556df443eb.